# How to transform a DEM to a cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: grass-gis, coordinate-system, dem, srtm

I am using the script r.inund.fluv. I run the script with all the required parameters and it produced a lot or errors.

I emailed the author of the script and he said that

*"I think you are not using a cartesian coordinate system... ("The DTM resolution is 0:00:03 x 0:00:03 meters") and the code work with a cartesian grid. "*

I'm using a raster map from SRTM for the elevation. Its DTM resolution is 0:00:03 x 0:00:03 meters. As what is required for the script to work, the author said that I should convert it to a cartesian coordinate system. How is it done for a raster SRTM map?

Comment: (-1) "0:00:03 meters" makes no sense.  This sounds like arc-seconds, not meters, as I'm sure is explained in the SRTM metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean 3 arc-seconds? That indicates LatLong. You will have to create a GRASS location with UTM or Lambert LAEA/LCC or another metric coordinate system and run r.inund.fluv therein. See also "[GRASS GIS projection intro](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/projectionintro.html)".